# Multiple lines on a plot using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am generating 4 rectangles using `ax.add_patch`. I want to connect these rectangles using single lines as shown in the expected output.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
n=2
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n):
        rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle((200+200*i,200+200*j),10*n, 10*n, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='black')
        ax.add_patch(rect)

ax.set_xlim(left = 0, right = 220*n)
ax.set_ylim(bottom = 0, top = 220*n)
plt.show()
```

The current output is

[image]

The expected output is

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try placing vertical and horizontal lines at those positions

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
n=2
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n):
        rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle((200+200*i,200+200*j),10*n, 10*n, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='black')
        ax.add_patch(rect)
    ax.hlines(200+200*i+10, 200, 400, zorder=0)
    ax.vlines(200+200*i+10, 200, 400, zorder=0)

ax.set_xlim(left = 0, right = 220*n)
ax.set_ylim(bottom = 0, top = 220*n)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
w = 10
xy = 200
n=2
coords = []

ax.add_patch(mpl.patches.Rectangle((xy+w,xy+w),xy,xy, linewidth=1, fill=0, edgecolor='blue'))

for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n):
        rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle((xy+xy*i,xy+xy*j),w*n, w*n, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='black')
        ax.add_patch(rect)
        coords.append([rect.get_xy(), rect.get_height(), rect.get_width()])

ax.set_xlim(left = 0, right = 220*n)
ax.set_ylim(bottom = 0, top = 220*n)
plt.show()
```

Output
[image]